# why the root domain did not using https

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx as a proxy server, now I configurate the server side nginx like this way:

```
server{
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.top/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.top/privkey.pem;

    server_name www.example.top example.top;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/home_example;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/home_example;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @router;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    location @router {
        rewrite ^.*$ /index.html last;
    }
    gzip_static  on;

}
```

as far as I know, when I access the `https://www.example.com` and `https://example.com`, the both use the same way to access the website. But the actual result was that when I access `https://www.example.com`, it works fine. When I access to `https://example.com`, it tell me that the website not secure.

why would this happen? how I tweak my nginx configuration to fix this problem? I have tried to add a file `example-default.conf` like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name zhuolian.top;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/zhuolian.top/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/zhuolian.top/privkey.pem;
    return 301 https://www.zhuolian.top$request_uri;
}
```

still did not fix this problem. when I access the domian `https://example.com`, shows message like this:

```
This server could not prove that it is example.top; its security certificate is from *.example.top. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is your cert, not nginx. Can't say anything about it, because you didn't mention anything about it. It is possible to have one cert for both. If you can't change the cert:

Issue 2 certs and go like:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.top;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.top/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.top/private.pem;
    return 301 https://www.example.top$request_uri;
}
server{
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/www.example.top/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/www.example.top/privkey.pem;
    server_name www.example.top;
    ...
```

Or try to redirect before ssl kicks in (never tried):

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name example.top www.example.top ;

  if ($host = 'example.top') {
    return 301 https://www.example.top$request_uri;
  }

  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.top/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert/example.top/private.pem;
}
```

Comment: the first way, when I access `https://zhuolian.top/` tell me the site can not be reached. @araisch

Comment: have to generate a new certificate for domain `exmaple.top`? @araisch

Comment: for testing set same cert files (still complaining then) and you should be redirected to your www-domain (if you replaced all placeholders of example). If that works issue second cert for this (without www) or aquire cert for both, then go with your code or try the lower one if redirect goes before ssl-check (don't think so but give it a try).